# How to remove one occurrence from Mysql table ?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table with the following fields  :

```
 PersonnelTable Table fields:

 * FirstName
 * LastName
 * Address
 * IdNumber
 * UserName
 * Password
 * Status
```

In that table I allow duplicate records .

I want to remove one occurrence from that table where :

```
String sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = ? AND `UserName` = ? ";
m_prepared.setString(1, _password);  // set the password
m_prepared.setString(2, _username);  // set the user-name
int rowsAffected = m_prepared.executeUpdate();
```

But that query would remove all the records where  `Password = ?` and `UserName = ?`

How can I remove only **one** record using that query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause can be used in `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements too:

```
"DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = ? AND `UserName` = ? LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove only one record using that query ?

You can use the "LIMIT 1" clause of mySQL's DELETE statement.

But if you want to remove all but last rows, you need to do this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = ? AND `UserName` = ? FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = ? AND `UserName` = ? LIMIT ?; # (last fetched count - 1)
COMMIT;
```